# Unable to perform interactive git rebase with emacs as the default editor

Tags: git, emacs, interactive, git-rebase

I am unable to successfully perform a 'git rebase -i' from the command line using emacs as my default editor. I can edit the file but cannot write it. The error emacs is reporting is that the git-rebase-todo file is read-only, but looking at the permissions for the file that was generated from another terminal I can see it is not. Changing my git config to use vi as the default editor does work and allows me to rebase my projects locally. This is baffling, to say the least. It feels like some kind of permissions problem due to an emacs misconfiguration somewhere.

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. My tools are gnu emacs 26.3 and git 2.25.1.

I looked on the web for other problems similar to this, but none seemed to be resolved yet they were closed. Seems like people are seeing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've no idea why you experience an issue with `emacs` as `core.editor`. Anyway, if you are interested in using emacs+`git rebase --interactive`, I'd strongly recommend to give a try to [`Magit`](https://magit.vc/) − and there are many tutorials or videos on the web that illustrate the `"git rebase -i $SHA"` workflow using Magit (i.e., without typing the command itself in a terminal, but directly via an emacs keybinding). E.g., https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtliRYQd0j4

Comment: This is still an issue, even more so now, since I now have a second Linux box configured like the first listed above, and it too experiences the same problem using emacs as the default editor while rebasing. I appreciate there are developers who use magit but I am not one, so answers suggesting I use magit are interesting but not helpful.

Comment: OK but anyway, your question lackes some details. E.g., what is the **mode** used by emacs to display the buffer (do e.g. `M-: mode-name RET`)? what is the precise contents of the buffer? would the keybinding `C-x C-q` workaround the issue?

Comment: Here's what I can tell you:
1. The major-mode is 'git-rebase-mode'
2. The keybinding C-x C-q does take the buffer out of read-only mode, but I can't write it. Any keypresses have no effect.
3. The buffer contents are what you'd expect during a rebase:

pick a0ddc87 Comment for this SHA
pick 90e55a4 Comment for this SHA

# Rebase 0224d9e..90e55a4 onto 0224d9e (2 commands)
#
# Commands:
# The remainder of the comments you'd expect to see

Answer (score 0):

According to the details you provided in the comments, the major mode enabled in your case is `git-rebase-mode`.

Actually, this mode is related to Magit itself: see e.g. [this file in the GitHub repository of Magit](https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/25f432551347468ce97b8b03987e59092e91f8f0/lisp/git-rebase.el#L692-L698).

Therefore:

1. either you find it convenient to rely on the features of this mode (see e.g. [this online doc](https://magit.vc/manual/2.13.0/magit.html#Editing-Rebase-Sequences));
2. or you might want to find the location of the Magit emacs package and remove it.

If ever you choose the option 2, some hints:

- Run <kbd>C-h v load-history RET</kbd>, <kbd>C-x o</kbd>, and <kbd>C-s git-rebase</kbd> to locate where `git-rebase.elc` is stored.
- If it's in your `$HOME/.emacs.d/elpa/` folder, the appropriate action is obvious;
- otherwise if it's in `/usr/share/emacs/26.3/lisp/`, you'd need to rely on your distribution package manager to figure out how to uninstall Magit.

Comment: Great! This is good info. I will investigate further and get back to this thread. In the meantime, I didn't install magit, so since it's there it's installed by default, perhaps as part of the Ubuntu 20.04 package. I use emacs at work running on Ubuntu 18.xx and do not have this problem. I need to check and see what version of emacs is running on my work laptop. Regardless, I'll get back to you in a while, perhaps tomorrow. Thanks Erik.

Comment: Haven't had a chance yet to try your suggestions, but I wanted to put the versions from an environment that I use daily and does not exhibit the problems I am seeing: emacs is 25.2, and git is 2.17. Ubuntu is 18.04